# comparing lists and finding unique entries

Tags: list, comparison, unix

I have two lists of names, A and B. I need to produce three lists:

1) names only on A

2) names only on B

3) names on both A and B

I also have a list with all the names on A and B, C.

Can anyone think of Unix tools or quick scripts to do this?

Answer (score 1):

use the command comm.

This does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Using the -1, -2, -3 flags I was able to supress the output and get exactly what I wanted.

comm [OPTION]... LEFT_FILE RIGHT_FILE  
DESCRIPTION

Compare sorted files LEFT_FILE and RIGHT_FILE line by line.

-1
    suppress lines unique to left file 
-2
    suppress lines unique to right file 
-3
    suppress lines that appear in both files

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to SORT your input files before feeding them into comm.  This can be done like this:

comm <(sort -u left_file) <(sort -u right_file)